# Multiplication problem involving kind `Nat`

Tags: haskell, data-kinds

Why does addition, subtraction and division of `Nat`s work, but not multiplication?

```
λ> :set -XDataKinds
λ> :set -XTypeOperators
λ> import GHC.TypeLits
λ> :k! 1 + 2
1 + 2 :: Nat
= 3
λ> :k! 1 - 2
1 - 2 :: Nat
= 1 - 2
λ> :k! 5 `Div` 2
5 `Div` 2 :: Nat
= 2
λ> :k! 1 * 2

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> Nat -> k0’, but ‘1’ has kind ‘Nat’
    • In the type ‘1 * 2’
```

Comment: With `*` refers to the `Type` kind. You should explicitly use `*` so `:k 1 GHC.TypeLits.* 2`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `*` was used to specify a simple `Type`. As a result `1` is seen as something that takes as first type parameter a `*` (so `Type`) and as second type parameter a `2`, and thus `1` should have kind `* -> Nat -> something`. GHC will parse an asterisk (`*`) as a reference to `Type` if the [**`StarIsType`** extension](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/migration/8.6#staristype) is enabled, which is the default.

If you disable it, then the asterisk (`*`) will refer to the multiplication, for example:

```
Prelude> :set -XDataKinds 
Prelude> :set -XTypeOperators
Prelude> :set -XNoStarIsType
Prelude> import GHC.TypeLits
Prelude GHC.TypeLits> :k 1 * 2
1 * 2 :: Nat
Prelude GHC.TypeLits> :kind! 1 * 2
1 * 2 :: Nat
= 2
```

You can also explicitly specify the module where you use the `*` type family family from with:

```
Prelude> :set -XDataKinds 
Prelude> :set -XTypeOperators
Prelude> import GHC.TypeLits
Prelude GHC.TypeLits> :k 1 GHC.TypeLits.* 2
1 GHC.TypeLits.* 2 :: Nat
Prelude GHC.TypeLits> :kind! 1 GHC.TypeLits.* 2
1 GHC.TypeLits.* 2 :: Nat
= 2
```

Comment: Great! Also, with `-XNoStarIsType`, GHC prints the kind for types as `Type` rather than `*`, which is clearer.